# How can i find missing id's in mysql

Tags: mysql

i have a large MySQL Database with more than 1 Million rows. How can i find the missing eid's?

```
+----+-----+
| id | eid |
+----+-----+
|  1 |  1  |
+----+-----+
|  2 |  2  |
+----+-----+
|  3 |  4  |
+----+-----+
```

I like to list all missing eid's, the 3 in this example. I've tried many things but everything what i do need to much time.

I hope someone can help me.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe 5  is missing too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`NOT EXISTS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) to find the required rows.

```
create table t(id integer, eid integer);
insert into t values(1,1);
insert into t values(2,2);
insert into t values(3,4);

SELECT id
FROM t a
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    ( SELECT 1
     FROM t b
     WHERE b.eid = a.id );
```

or use `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT ID
FROM t
WHERE ID NOT IN
    (SELECT EID
     FROM t);
```

produces:

```
| id |
|----|
|  3 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query

```
SELECT ID FROM table WHERE ID NOT IN(SELECT EID FROM table );
```

Comment: The result of this query is: Empty set (5.35 sec)

Comment: hi, i've ran this query 18 hours ago and waiting for the result. is that normal?

Comment: It's not normal, what is your primary key, just describe the table and post it.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `br_merge` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `amtsgericht` text NOT NULL,
  `aktenzeichen` text NOT NULL,
  `bekanntgemacht` text NOT NULL,
  `content_1` longtext NOT NULL,
  `eintragungsart` text NOT NULL,
  `eintragungsdate` text NOT NULL,
  `content_2` longtext NOT NULL,
  `eid` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: ALTER TABLE `br_merge`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

Comment: ALTER TABLE `br_merge`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=1362200;

Answer (score 0):

Finding duplicate numbers is easy:

select id, count(*) from sequence
group by id
having count(*) > 1;

In this case there are no duplicates, since I’m not concentrating on that in this post (finding duplicates is straightforward enough that I hope you can see how it’s done). I had to scratch my head for a second to find missing numbers in the sequence, though. Here is my first shot at it:

select l.id + 1 as start
from sequence as l
  left outer join sequence as r on l.id + 1 = r.id
where r.id is null;

The idea is to exclusion join against the same sequence, but shifted by one position. Any number with an adjacent number will join successfully, and the WHERE clause will eliminate successful matches, leaving the missing numbers. Here is the result:

https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2005/12/06/find-missing-numbers-in-a-sequence-with-sql/

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') from sequence group by id having count() > 1 LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

if you want a lighter way to search millions of rows of data,

I was try for search in more than 23 millions rows with old CPU (12.6Gb data need about 1gb of free ram):
*Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 346.764  Warnings: 0  Duration for 2 queries: 00:04:48.0 (+ 2,656 sec. network)*

```
SET @idBefore=0, @st=0,@diffSt=0,@diffEnd=0;
SELECT res.idBefore `betweenID`, res.ID `andNextID`
 , res.startEID, res.endEID
 , res.diff `diffEID`
-- DON'T USE this missingEIDfor more than a thousand of rows
-- this is just for sample view
 , GROUP_CONCAT(b.aNum) `missingEID`
FROM (
  SELECT
    @idBefore `idBefore`
    , @idBefore:=(a.id) `ID`
    , @diffSt:=(@st) `startEID`
    , @diffEnd:=(a.eid) `endEID`
    , @st:=a.eid `end`
    , @diffEnd-@diffSt-1 `diff`
    FROM eid a 
  ORDER BY a.ID
  ) res
-- DON'T USE this integers for more than a thousand of rows
-- this is just for sample view
CROSS JOIN (SELECT a.ID + (b.ID * 10) + (c.ID * 100) AS aNum FROM integers a, integers b, integers c) b
WHERE res.diff>0 AND b.aNum BETWEEN res.startEID+1 AND res.endEID-1
GROUP BY res.ID;
```

check out this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/33deb3/9
and this is for missing ID http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3ea00c/9